# keep a variable not-local but not global in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-nonlocal

So I have a small bit of code in python 3.4.1 where I'm just playing with closures

```
def bam(x):
    def paw():
        x+=1
        print(x)
    def bang():
        x+=1
        print(x)
    return paw, bang
```

originally I wanted to see if I could call

```
a=bam(56)
a[0]()
a[0]()
a[0]()
a[0]()
a[1]()
```

and then see if the final line would print a number greater than 56 like it would it javascript (I think)

but instead its making 'x' in 'paw' local because I called `+=` (right?) and its throwing an error when It tries to GET it in `x+=1`

```
  File "C:/Users/Nancy/Desktop/delete2.py", line 3, in paw
    x+=1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

is there some sort of rule against modifying variables in an outer scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *assigning to `x`*, which means that Python defaults to `x` being a local.

Explicitly tell Python it is `nonlocal` instead:

```
def bam(x):
    def paw():
        nonlocal x
        x+=1
        print(x)
    def bang():
        nonlocal x
        x+=1
        print(x)
    return paw, bang
```

Comment: aaah thank you, does nonlocal/global x have to come before the assignment?